# Looping through tests in Nightwatch using Mocha

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, nightwatch.js

I'm using Nightwatch with Mocha to write some automated (dynamic) tests. Dynamic in the sense that I want to load some of the data dynamically which is used in looping through test cases. See code below. I am struggling with three items:

1. Let's say I end up with 3 items in my testArray. When it loops in the test (it), its only opens one browser, goes to google.com and doesn't start 2 other browsers.  I'm sure this is related to some async issue I'm having but I don't know how to resolve it.
2. Continuing from #1, the first (and only browser opened) doesn't even close at the conclusion.  Again an async issue with some aspect of using done().
3. Ideally I would like to dynamically name the test while it's running. i.e., instead of it("foo"... I would like to either have the loop around the it and pass in the title (which I can't get working right) or somehow change it within the test (it) code dynamically.

Note that I don't need to use Mocha with Nightwatch but I started going down the path of using Mocha's dynamic test feature (new TestCase) but I couldn't get that working either.

Here is a scaled-down version of my code.

```
var testArray = [];

describe('createArray', function() {
  before(function(client, done) {
    // do some async operations within a loop and create testArray entries
    // loop {
        testArray.push(foo); // let's say I end up with 3 items.
    // }
    done();
  });

  it('foo', function(client) {
    console.log(testCaseArray);
    testCaseArray.forEach(function(testCase) {
      client.url("http://www.google.com"); // let's say here I would eventually want to have something like client.url("http://....." + testCase.value)
    });
  });
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you need to handle the test cases asynchronously. It could be done like this:

```
it('foo', function(client, done) {
  var testsLeft = testCaseArray.length;
  function onTestComplete() {
    testsLeft--;
    if (testsLeft === 0)
      done();
  }
  testCaseArray.forEach(function(testCase) {
    client.url("http://" + testCase.value, onTestComplete);
  });
});
```

I'm not familiar with Nightwatch so you may need to use `onTestComplete` like this:

```
client.url("http://" + testCase.value).end(onTestComplete);
```

Also, I realize that's a pretty verbose way of handling the asynchronous callbacks. Normally for this type of situation it's helpful to use something like [CallbackManager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callbackmanager) so you don't need to manually keep track of how many tests are left.

#### Update:

You could also dynamically generate your tests as per the [Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  For some reason I still can't get it working. The client.url function gets called twice but only one browser is still showing. Maybe nightwatch (or mocha) only allows one session within a test?

Comment: Actually I did get it working via using client.session('delete'); and client.session('create');  I realize now that it would be better if I could have the loop outside of the it so that each test runs separately and fails separately.  I marked your answer as correct.

Comment: Yes you could that. I added updated my answer to include a link to an example of putting the loop around the tests (just for completeness since you've probably already figured out how to do that).